# Manually set connection as secure nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx

We've hardcoded our application with the sha keys and now the certificate on the server expired. We're using nginx and would like to know if there is any way to manually set connection as secure even if the sha keys on the client are not valid.

Thanks.

Comment: "hardcoded our application with the sha keys" - can you please elaborate?  Do you mean that you've hardcoded your application to trust only certain key fingerprint(s)?

Comment: yes. We have the shaKeys (fingerprint) added in the app(hybrid app) code itself. We're using this plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin to verify the connection security.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should renew the server certificate so that client are not receiving a certificate that is expired.  You can use the same key on the new certificate, so your clients will accept the new certificate because it is not expired, and the fingerprint of the (unchanged) key will still be recognised by the client software.

As a less desirable option, since you are explicitly trusting particular key fingerprint(s), you might be able to configure the clients to ignore the fact that the certificate is expired.